# Как настроить __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, init

У меня есть папка, в ней лежит файл `test.py` и папка `test`, в папке `test` есть файл `__init__.py` с командой `from .full import *` и сам файл `full.py`, дело в том, что я хочу, чтобы при запуске из первоначальной папки команды `import test` импортировался файл `test.py`, а если `import test.full`, то папка `test/full.py`. У меня сначала получилось это сделать с помощью `__init__.py`, но начудил и теперь ничего не работает, всегда импортируется только файл из папки `test`, т.к. в начальной папке питон попросту не видит инит файл. Кто может помочь с инит файлами и их расположениями? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен. Что такое `рабочая папка` и чем она отличается от `главной папки` ? Запуск из главной папки `команды import test` - это как, что и как вы запускаете. Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @s.Nick ничем не отличается, а import test - это я импортирую свою библиотеку (файл test.py), примера нету, все что возможно - написал, тут не совсем в коде дело.